# what does one need to consider when setting up a backup dhcp server?

Tags: linux, dhcp

I have a server running dnsmasq... 
I'd like to add a second one that only gets used if the first is unavailable.

Is this possible without too much automation?

For now I've just configured one to distributed 0-50 and the other 51-100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [check_dhcp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_dhcp) Nagios plugins. Add to root crontab in backup server(change eth0):

```
*/5 * * * *   check_dhcp  -i eth0 || service dnsmasq start
```

Better use ISC DHCP and DHCP failover.

Comment: not a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

You did the right thing. DHCP works as follows: 
The client makes a request (DHCPDISCOVER).
The client receives just 2 suggestions (DHCPOFFER). Both proposals are unique, each proposal contains details of the server that sent it. 2 or more requests can not interfere with each other.
The client chooses one of them, then communicates (DHCPREQUEST) to the one chosen.

But does it make sense to create a cumbersome system, if the term of the lease Ip-addresses is 8 days, and new DHCP rises for 20 minutes?